# Draw shapes and can select each shape

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an imageview inside a scrollview, then I want to draw/place shapes like lines on the the image.

Tricky part is I need to use gestures/touches to select each shape.

What is the best approach to implement that?

Comment: What is your final output?

Comment: My final output is like, if i have an image if square, then draw a square with 4 lines.

Comment: I need to be able to select each of the 4 lines then can delete it maybe or change its color, anything.